# Return parent node with jq while querying one of its children

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix, jq

Wondering if its possible to return the parent "Id" from the json below while querying the child "Id"

```
{
    "DistributionList": {
        "Items": [
            {
                "Origins": {
                    "Items": [
                        {
                            "Id": "abc"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Quantity": 1
                },
                "Id": "parent123"
            },
            {
                "Origins": {
                    "Items": [
                        {
                            "Id": "def"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Quantity": 1
                },
                "Id": "parent345"
            }
         ]
    }
}
```

Eg. If I query for child id "abc" it should return "parent123".

Doing something like:

```
more jsonfile | jq '.DistributionList.Items[].Origins.Items[] | select(.Id == "abc") | .Id'
```

will only return "abc" -> but i need the parent id.
Not sure if there is way to do this with jq

Comment: how about something like this without using jq:  `grep -oP '(?<=Id":)\s*".*$' data.txt | sed -n 's/^/child: /;N;s/\n/ has parent Id: /;p'`

Comment: @ritesht93 im just getting a grep usage help text with that command under my mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter:

```
.. | objects | select(.Origins.Items[]? | .Id == "abc") | .Id
```

produces:

```
"parent123"
```

You might want to parameterize the filter, e.g.:

```
def parent(child):
 .. | objects | select( .Origins.Items[]? | .Id == child) | .Id ;
```

Comment: `more filename | jq '.. | objects | select(.Origins.Items[]? | .Id == "xxx") | .Id'` did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The filter in the original question is close to a solution.  All that's needed is to rearrange what goes in the `select`.  E.g.

```
  .DistributionList.Items[]
| select(.Origins.Items[].Id == "abc")
| .Id
```